# Is there a way to access @Input variables in a dynamically created component?

Tags: angular

I'm dynamically adding rows to a form and want each new row to have a unique id number.

I have the following code to add a new component (representing a new row), but I find that `component.instance` contains only the "normal" properties of the newly-created component, not the properties decorated with `@Input()`. Is there any way to dynamically write-to/modify the `@Input()` properties? When one dynamically creates a component, one would naturally assume there has to be a straightforward way to provide the @Input() values somehow!

```js
const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(thisType);
const component = this.subEnrollForm.container.createComponent(componentFactory);
component.instance.rowData.push(newRow); //rowData is a property in the
                                       dynamically-created component and 
                                       is decorated with @Input()
```

Here's the dynamically-created component:

```js
export class SubEnrollFormRowComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck, OnChanges, AfterContentInit, AfterViewInit {
 @Input() rowData; 
  objKeys: Array<any> = [];
  subKeys: Array<any> = [];
```

I saw an old posting that had the following answer, but am hoping that subsequently there have been new features added to address this issue:

> No, Angular2 bindings only work with components and directives
>   statically added to the template of a component.
>
> For all other situations use shared services like explained in
>   https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service
>
> You can also use
>
> let componentRef = entryPoint.createComponent(componentFactory);
>   componentRef.instance.someProp = 'someValue';
>   componentRef.instance.someObservableOrEventEmitter.subscribe(data =>
>   this.prop = data);

That latter solution didn't work for me, nor did another suggestion to cast the component to type `<any>`. My interpretation of the `services` approach mentioned above is that I would need to create an Observable for the grandchild to subscribe to, to monitor when the grandparent attempts to update the grandchild's @Input() property, but this approach seems to me to be massive overkill with a lot of unnecessary coding and overhead to achieve something that should be very simple and straightforward (unless I'm missing something, which is very likely!). So many thanks in advance if anyone has a relatively easy way to initialize/dynamically modify a grandchild component property that's decorated with @Input!

Comment: One solution may be to add a property that's not decorated with @Input, and then use that property to update the `@Input` property in a subsequent lifecycle hook . . . but again, that seems like a bit of a hack and I'd love to know if there's a more elegant/direct way to update/write-to the `@Input` properties . . .

Comment: This has always been possible. Working example from the angular documentation: https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/dynamic-component-loader/stackblitz.html. The components `hero-job-ad` and `hero-job-profile` are dynamically created with their `@Input() data` property set at runtime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Properties decorated with `@Input` are still class properties, and are accessible like any other property.

I have created a working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-template-yih3sx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Very nice example.

Comment: Many thanks, and much appreciated! So unless I'm misreading, it looks like the trick is in:`(<AdComponent>componentRef.instance).data = adItem.data;` where we're casting the component with the `@Input` into a different type where the `data` property is not decorated with `@Input` . . . Fiendishly clever!

Comment: That is not a requirement. The Angular example does that because their example is a little more complex. If you look at my example, I'm casting to `DynamicComponent`, which still has the `@Input` decorator, and still works. The decorator does not affect/hide properties in any way.